# KMeans clustering of textual data

Tags: python, dataframe, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a pandas dataframe with the following 2 columns:

```
      Database Name             Name

      db1_user                  Login
      db1_client                Login
      db_care                   Login
      db_control                LoginEdit
      db_technology             View
      db_advanced               LoginEdit
```

I have to cluster the Database Name based on the field “Name”. When I convert it to a numpy, using

dataset = df2.values

When I print the print(dataset.dtype), the type is object. I have just started with Clustering, from what I read, I understand that object is not a type suitable for Kmeans clustering.

Any help would be appreicated!!

Answer (score 0):

What is the **mean** of

```
Login
LoginEdit
View
```

supposed to be?

There is a reason why k-means only works on continuous numerical data. Because the *mean* requires such data to be well defined.

I don't think clustering is applicable on your problem *at all* (rather look into data cleaning). But clearly you need a method that works with arbitrary distances - k-mean does not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand whether you want to develop clusters for each GROUP of "Name" Attributes, or alternatively create n clusters regardless of the value of "Name"; and I don't understand what clustering could achieve here.

In any case, just a few days ago there was a similar question on the datascience SE site (from an R user, though), asking for similarity of local-names of email addresses (the part before the "@"), not of database-names. The problem is similar to yours.

Check this out:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14146/text-similarities/14148#14148

The answer was  comprehensive with respect to the **different distance measures for strings**.

Maybe this is what you should investigate. Then decide on a proper distance measure that is available in python (or one that you can program yourself), and that fits your needs.